# Python typing valid boolean combinations

Tags: python, mypy, static-typing

I'm trying to use Python's type checker to catch incompatible permissions. I have a permission situation where a particular action can be permitted (boolean) and required (boolean). Obviously, I want to rule out the situation where it is forbidden and also required, since this is impossible.

Here's what I have tried.

```
Permissions = Union[
    Tuple[Literal[False], Literal[False]],  # forbidden and not required
    Tuple[Literal[True], Literal[False]],   # permitted and not required
    Tuple[Literal[True], Literal[True]]     # permitted and required
    # (No option for forbidden and required)
]

forbidden: Permissions = (False, False)
allowed: Permissions = (True, False)
required: Permissions = (True, True)
mypy_should_catch: Permissions = (False, True)
```

I expect mypy to allow the first three, but disallow the last.

However, what I actually get is an error like this for all four:

```
error: Incompatible types in assignment (expression has type "Tuple[bool, bool]", variable has type "Union[Tuple[Literal[False], Literal[False]], Tuple[Literal[True], Literal[False]], Tuple[Literal[True], Literal[True]]]")
```

How can I make this work?

Comment: it may help to see where you're using `Permissions`

Comment: Do you need your Permissions tuples to contain `Literal[False]`? I'm not really sure why you need the `Literal` part and not just have the `False` etc.

Comment: @CmdCoder858 they're making a type alias. `False` isn't a type. `Literal[False]` is.

Comment: Ah thank you. Sorry I'm not very familiar with this topic.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

mypy 0.941 does catch the last line only:

```
$ mypy test.py
test.py:13: error: Incompatible types in assignment (expression has type "Tuple[bool, bool]", variable has type "Union[Tuple[Literal[False], Literal[False]], Tuple[Literal[True], Literal[False]], Tuple[Literal[True], Literal[True]]]")  [assignment]
Found 1 error in 1 file (checked 1 source file)
```

So it looks like you just need to upgrade.

Answer (score 0):

In the end I went a slightly different direction in trying to capture the logic of forbidden/permitted/required in a type-safe way.

```
class Permissions(Enum):
    FORBIDDEN = auto()
    PERMITTED = auto()
    REQUIRED = auto()

    @property
    def permitted(self) -> bool:
        return self is not self.FORBIDDEN

    @property
    def required(self) -> bool:
        return self is self.REQUIRED
```

However, I won't mark this as the answer as there's still the question of why the original approach didn't work as expected.